# Auto Open USB Drive on Mac 10.6/7/8/Windows XP/Vista/7

Tags: windows, macos, installation, usb

I'm creating a FAT32 formatted USB Stick/Drive to ship a product. We'd like it to behave a bit more like the hybrid CD/DVD's that we create:

1. Insert the disk on Mac 10.6 or later and the drive opens up and shows you a window with the application in it. We can do it from a DMG or CD but the USB drive doesn't seem to want to honor the `bless` command.
2. On Windows, we've set up an autorun.inf. On XP it's not showing the icon, label, or opening the specified file. I know that you can't have Windows Vista and Windows 7 automatically open something or add an entry to the AutoPlay list by default, but it still should show the Volume Label and icon.

Here is my autorun.inf:

```
[AutoRun]
Action="Install My Cool App"
Open="InstallThis.exe"
icon="Ultimate.ico"

[Content]
MusicFiles=false
PictureFiles=false
VideoFiles=false
```

Are these things too much to ask for a USB stick? Anyone else out there shipping things on a USB flash drive and have overcome these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Windows 7, AutoRun feature is not supported on USB drives. Only the following commands are supported:

- label
- icon

See [Improvements to AutoPlay](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/e7/archive/2009/04/27/improvements-to-autoplay.aspx) on Engineering Windows 7 blog.

Examples in [Autorun.inf Entries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) do not use quotes for values. Does it work without the quotes?

---

MacOS might have implemented a similar approach to Windows 7: do not autorun anything from a flash drive automatically to protect you from malware.